# Can I use AWS User Pools as a directory service from a Spring app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to use AWS Cognito User Pools as an authentication and authorisation provider for a Spring Boot app running in EC2?

The user pools seem to provide a lot of the regsiter/login/email/forgotpassword etc plumbing, that I can make use of in an AngularJS front end.

If the front end does all the auth (in javascript), can a java (spring) backend verify tokens passed to it from the front end, and if so how?

Or, can/should the calls to Cognito come from the backend, and again, if so how? Do I need to use the AWS Android mobile SDK?

(I've looked at Lambdas and Api Gateways but they are not what I am after at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one of those options should work, depending a bit on your app requirements. The former does have the benefit of sending user credentials over the wire less often than the latter.

If you want to verify the tokens with your first suggestion, you could do one of a few things. Cognito vends an id token, a refresh token, and an access token upon a user authenticating. Any call that takes an access token (i.e. GetUser) does validation on that access token. Alternatively, you could make a call to refresh the tokens, which will do validation on the refresh token. More information on the tokens Cognito vends is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html). Token refreshing is done through the Cognito [auth flow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html), using challenge name REFRESH_TOKEN or REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH.

If you opt to go with the second one, AWS does have multiple SDKs for various languages, including Java. These all support the Cognito APIs, but Cognito does use SRP to sign users in. The client side calculations are fairly complex, so you might not want to take that on yourself. You could rip our calculations from the [SDK on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android), or you could use the admin no SRP flow described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some more digging. I just wanted to make sure I was on the right path.

Comment: @Rob how does it go ? did you make the token validation inside your Spring server ?